# Problems on sorting an array in my function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function which sort an array and I met a problem. When I sort an array it always return 0 in first position of sorted array. No matter what combination it is.

```
 void sorting(int wielkosc)
{
    int t[wielkosc];
   //filling 
    for (int i = 0; i < wielkosc; i++)
    {
        t[i] = rand()% 100 + 1;
    }

    // before sort
    cout << "before sorting: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < wielkosc; i++)
    {
        cout << "[" << i << "] -> " << t[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // asc...
    int iTemp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < wielkosc; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= wielkosc; j++)
        {
           //jak chcesz zmienic na malejaco to se przekrec '<' na '>'
        if (t[j] < t[i])
        {

        iTemp = t[i];
        t[i] = t[j];
        t[j] = iTemp;
        }}}
    // after sorting
    cout << "after sorting: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < wielkosc; i++)
    {
        cout << "[" << i << "] -> " << t[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: a) this is not C b) `int t[wielkosc];` is not standard C++ c) don't use random numbers for testing and debugging. d) did you use a debugger?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of a variable-length array.  And use `std::sort()` instead of manual loops.

Comment: fwiw, no random input because with random input you have 1 trial to get correct output for a test case, next time you will have a different test case. As long as your code has bugs you certainly need more than one shot to make a test case pass. Once you pass one you can turn to the next.

Comment: a) ok, b) ok, c) ok, d) ye

Comment: `t[j]` is out of bounds when `j == wielkosc`, thats undefined behavior. Unless you fix that output could be anything